# Define an exact DateTime format permitted for .NET WebApi controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a common controller in WebAPI .NET:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/report")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ItemsByDate(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {...}
```

And presently the behind-the-scenes parsing is "clever" and I can pass DateTime in a multitude of formats.

In order to make it standard for my clients, I want to restrict DateTime accepted by that method to a certain format (let's say mm-YYYY, could be one of standard [IS08601 options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)). If the format is violated, I would like REST call to return an error.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'd personally just make sure that the documentation *examples* use one consistent format and, if necessary, you call out a "preferred" format - but if they're reached the point where the framework is actually calling `ItemsByDate`, you know that *whatever* they passed could be interpreted as a datetime. Why otherwise try to penalise a valid caller?

Comment: And I would recommend that your preference by the ISO standard.

Comment: Also, hopefully final thought - no amount of testing can protect you against some issues. Most notably, for the first twelve days of each month, when someone submits a date `NNNN-NN-NN` where each `N` date is a digit, there's no way *programmatically* to know whether they intended `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-DD-MM`.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved using a custom directive.

An example of making custom directive with similar purpose can be found here: https://gist.github.com/vickramravichandran/17a3326e44b14144b3e4b81643c59bff